# Huge memory allocation running a julia function?

Tags: performance, julia

I try to run the following function in julia command, but when timing the function I see too much memory allocations which I can't figure out why.

```
function pdpf(L::Int64, iters::Int64)
snr_dB = -10 
snr = 10^(snr_dB/10) 
Pf = 0.01:0.01:1      
thresh = rand(100)
Pd     = rand(100)

for m = 1:length(Pf)
    i = 0
    for k = 1:iters 
        n = randn(L) 
        s = sqrt(snr) * randn(L) 
        y = s + n 

        energy_fin = (y'*y) / L
        @inbounds thresh[m] = erfcinv(2Pf[m]) * sqrt(2/L) + 1

        if energy_fin[1] >= thresh[m]
            i += 1   
        end
    end
    @inbounds Pd[m] = i/iters
end

#thresh = erfcinv(2Pf) * sqrt(2/L) + 1
#Pd_the = 0.5 * erfc(((thresh - (snr + 1)) * sqrt(L)) / (2*(snr + 1)))

end
```

Running that function in the julia command on my laptop, I get the following shocking numbers:

```
julia> @time pdpf(1000, 10000)
 17.621551 seconds (9.00 M allocations: 30.294 GB, 7.10% gc time)
```

What is wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this memory allocation is so surprising.  For instance, consider all of the times that the inner loop gets executed:

`for m = 1:length(Pf)` this gives you 100 executions

`for k = 1:iters` this gives you 10,000 executions based on the arguments you supply to the function.

`randn(L)` this gives you a random vector of length 1,000, based on the arguments you supply to the function.

Thus, just considering these, you've got 100*10,000*1000 = 1 billion Float64 random numbers being generated.  Each one of them takes 64 bits = 8 bytes.  I.e. 8GB right there.  And, you've got two calls to `randn(L)` which means that you're at 16GB allocations already.

You then have `y = s + n` which means another 8GB allocations, taking you up to 24GB.  I haven't looked in detail on the remaining code to get you from 24GB to 30GB allocations, but this should show you that it's not hard for the GB allocations to start adding up in your code.

If you're looking at places to improve, I'll give you a hint that these lines can be improved by using the properties of normal random variables:

```
    n = randn(L) 
    s = sqrt(snr) * randn(L) 
    y = s + n
```

You should easily be able to cut down the allocations here from 24GB to 8GB in this way.  Note that `y` will be a normal random variable here as you've defined it, and think up a way to generate a normal random variable with an identical distribution to what `y` has now.

Another small thing, `snr` is a constant inside your function.  Yet, you keep taking its `sqrt` 1 million separate times.  In some settings, 'checking your work' can be helpful, but I think that you can be confident the computer will get it right the first time and thus you don't need to make it keep re-doing this calculation ; ).  There are other similar places you can improve your code to avoid duplicate computations here that I'll leave to you to locate.

Comment: ,@aireties -- Thank you for your explanation. Actually, I can't cut iteration numbers or even vector length because the curve is still too course. And yes, I noticed that about 70% of the time is spent in `randn()` but I can't find another faster `randn()` and want to increase `iters` to 100,000 at least. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @AboAmmar I added some updates with suggestions on reducing the numbers of calculations and random number generations.

Comment: ,@aireties -- Thank you, I will try to use a single `randn()` as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

aireties gives a good answer for why you have so many allocations. You can do more to reduce the number of allocations. Using [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) we know that `y = s+n` is really `y = sqrt(snr) * randn(L)  + randn(L)` and so we can instead do `y = rvvar*randn(L)` where `rvvar= sqrt(1+sqrt(snr)^2)` is defined outside the loop (thanks for the fix!). This will halve the number of random variables needed.

Outside the loop you can save `sqrt(2/L)` to cut down a little bit of time.

I don't think transpose is special-cased yet, so try using `dot(y,y)` instead of `y'*y`. I know `dot` for sure is just a loop without having to transpose, while the other may transpose depending on the version of Julia.

Something that would help performance (but not allocations) would be to use one big randn(L,iters) and loop through that. The reason is because if you make all of your random numbers all at once it's faster since it can use SIMD and a bunch of other goodies. If you want to implicitly do that without changing your code much, you can use [ChunkedArrays.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/ChunkedArrays.jl) where you can use `rands = ChunkedArray(randn,L)` to initialize it and then everytime you want a `randn(L)`, you instead use `next(rands)`. Inside the ChunkedArray it actually makes bigger vectors and replenishes them as needed, but like this you can just get your `randn(L)` without having to keep track of all of that.

Edit:

ChunkedArrays probably only save time when L is smaller. This gives the code:

```
function pdpf(L::Int64, iters::Int64)
snr_dB = -10
snr = 10^(snr_dB/10)
Pf = 0.01:0.01:1
thresh = rand(100)
Pd     = rand(100)
rvvar= sqrt(1+sqrt(snr)^2)

for m = 1:length(Pf)
    i = 0
    for k = 1:iters
      y = rvvar*randn(L)
      energy_fin = (y'*y) / L
      @inbounds thresh[m] = erfcinv(2Pf[m]) * sqrt(2/L) + 1

      if energy_fin[1] >= thresh[m]
          i += 1
      end
    end
    @inbounds Pd[m] = i/iters
end
end
```

which runs in half the time as using two randn calls. Indeed from the ProfileViewer we get:

```
@profile pdpf(1000, 10000)
using ProfileView
ProfileView.view()
```

[image]

I circled the two parts for the line `y = rvvar*randn(L)`, so the vast majority of the time is random number generation. Last time I checked you could still get a decent speedup on random number generation by changing to to [VSL.jl library](https://github.com/sunoru/VSL.jl), but you need MKL linked to your Julia build. Note that [from the Google Summer of Code page](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/6453977159827456/?sp-page=2#5411414587998208) you can see that there is a project to make a repo [RNG.jl](https://github.com/sunoru/RNG.jl) with faster psudo-rngs. It looks like it already has a few new ones implemented. You may want to check them out and see if they give speedups (or help out with that project!)

Comment: ,@ChrisRackauckas  -- Thank you for your answer. But I think the correct formula should be `rvvar = sqrt(1 + snr)` rather than the one you mentioned and yes, using `y = rvvar*randn(L)` can save a good deal of time. Other than this, I don't find any significant time saving ideas. Ideally, I am interested in finding a fast version of `randn` as I use this function extensively in my Monte-Carlo simulations.